# What does knowing one’s soul mean?

Tags: ramayana, philosophy, translation

When describing virtuous people one of the phrase that’s repeatedly used by Valmiki is विदितात्मनः

[valmikiramayana.net](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga2/sundarasans2.htm#Verse38) translates this to *the knower of self*.

Bibek Debroy (Chapter 5(2), Para 3) translates it to *who knows about his soul*.

What is meant by knowing one’s soul/self? Is it, in the modern lingo, **being self aware**? Or is it something deeper like knowing everything about oneself which might mean not having any confusion on how to act/react in any arbitrary situation? **If so, can someone provide me the relevant parts of the scriptures that describe this?**

I ask this because it might give an insight as to what our ancestors considered to be **the** state to aspire to/attain.

Comment: Though not related to your question, but what does your name mean?

Comment: King Kushanabha had 100 daughters before having a son, Gadhi (Vishwamitra’a father). https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga32/balasans32.htm#Verse11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the English word self or Self is often used by translators for the Sanskrit 'atman' which has no corresponding English translation. It was first suggested by German translators in the 19th century and has been commonly used since then.

Shankaracharya says in verse 20 of the Brahma Jnanavali Mala:

brahma satyam jagan-mithya jivo brahmaiva naparah anena vedyam sacchastram-iti vedanta-dindimah

Brahman is real, the universe is neither real nor unreal. The jiva is Brahman Itself and not different. This should be understood as the Truth of the scriptures. This is the drumbeat of Vedanta.

In the *Chandogya Upanishad*, Prajapati declares (verse 8.7.1, available here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc239454.html)

> य आत्मापहतपाप्मा विजरो विमृत्युर्विशोको विजिघत्सोऽपिपासः सत्यकामः सत्यसंकल्पः सोऽन्वेष्टव्यः स विजिज्ञासितव्यः स सर्वांश्च लोकानाप्नोति सर्वांश्च कामान्यस्तमात्मानमनुविद्य विजानातीति ह प्रजापतिरुवाच ॥ ८.७.१ ॥
>
> ya ātmāpahatapāpmā vijaro vimṛtyurviśoko vijighatso'pipāsaḥ satyakāmaḥ satyasaṃkalpaḥ so'nveṣṭavyaḥ sa vijijñāsitavyaḥ sa sarvāṃśca lokānāpnoti sarvāṃśca kāmānyastamātmānamanuvidya vijānātīti ha prajāpatiruvāca || 8.7.1 ||
>
> 1. Prajāpati once said: ‘The Self is free from sin, free from old age, free from death, free from sorrow, and free from hunger and thirst. It is the cause of desire for Truth and for commitment to Truth. This Self has to be sought for and thoroughly known. The person who has sought for and known the Self attains all worlds and all desires’.

The god Indra and demon Virocana hear what Prajapati says and go to him to be taught the nature of the self. You can then read their inquiry and results in the following sections through section/verse 8.7.2-8.12

Many teachers have said the same - Know your self. The only question to ask in this life is 'Who am I?'

Comment: Such a wonderful answer! Thank you for this.